# AWS Security Groups - Connecting EC2 to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AWS Security Groups - EC2 to RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672431/aws-security-groups-ec2-to-rds)

I have an EC2 instance running and a RDS instance running...

I also have 2 Security Groups:

1. Web Server Group:

   - Custom TCP rule 0.0.0.0/0 Port 80
   - SSH (Google My IP)/32
   - All TCP Traffic – (Source) Database Server Group
   - All ICMP – (Source) Database Server Group
   - All UDP – (Source) Database Server Group
2. Database Server Group:

   - Custom TCP Rule – Port 3306 Source Web Servers Group

Web Server Group is attached to EC2 instance at creation point and I can SSH and access websites on port 80 successfully. This group also access all TCP/ICMP/UDP access back from the RDS Instance via the Database Server Group.

Database Server Group is attached to RDS and allows port 3306.

What do I need to add to this to get MYSQL traffic to flow? - currently no flowing...

Note: If I attached the 'Web Server Group' to the RDS instance the MYSQL data flows. Don't want to leave this like this as RDS shouldn't get port 80 data etc.

Note: I've tried adding all TCP/UDP/ICMP traffice to the Database Server Group and this didn't help (just testing to see what would happen)...

thx

Comment: You should add some of this detail on your previously asked question rather than open a duplicate.  As with previously question the answer is that by attaching `Web Server Group` EC2 policy to the `Database Server Group` DB policy, you are only allowing convenient named port 3306-only access from the EC2 instances which subscribe to `Web Server Group` policy.  You do not convey any properties of the EC2 policy onto the DB server. In fact you should not really even think about RDS from a full-server perspective. Amazon protects all non-configured ports on their RDS domains. You have no control.

Comment: How did you solved? i am having a hard time dealing with this right now

Answer (score 1):

Above isn't the best way to do this...

An EC2 Group acts as a Access Control List and can be attached to an RDS Security Group no allowing outside access but only access from the EC2 instances in that group to the Database Port - In my case port 3306 MySQL.

cheers